# How to output EL as example

Tags: jsf, el

I am creating Facelet components for JSF to be used by other developers in my company. To help those, we have example pages set up, where you could see working examples and the source code to copy, paste and modify in other pages.

I need to show an examples of how to use EL in attributes, but I cannot get the EL to be printed out as String without an ugly workaround like

```
attribute="<h:outputText value="#"/>
<h:outputText value="{"/>
<h:outputText value="myExpression"/>
<h:outputText value="}"/>"
```

It works this way, but looks pretty dull to me. How to achieve my goal leaner and/or cleaner?

Comment: Like as with XML/HTML/JS, the right term is "escape". I.e. you want to escape EL. This in turn yields [much better results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=escape+el).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the  [Expression Language Specification Version 2.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) :

> To generate literal values that
>   include the character sequence `"${"`
>   or `"#{"`, the developer can choose to
>   use a composite expression as shown
>   here:
>
> ```
> ${'${'}exprA}
> #{'#{'}exprB}
> ```
>
> The resulting values would then be the
>   strings `${exprA}` and `#{exprB}`.
>
> Alternatively, the escape characters
>   `\$` and `\#` can be used to escape
>   what would otherwise be treated as an
>   eval-expression. Given the
>   literal-expressions:
>
> ```
> \${exprA}
> \#{exprB}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly input JSF in attributes without escaping it of course, it is not XML compliant to use `<` and `>` inside them. Also as you already seen `#{}` are rendered.

The easy way :

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;

public class Bean
{
    public String getValue()
    {
        return escapeHtml("<h:outputText value=\"#{myExpression}\" />");
    }
}

<yourComponent attribute="#{bean.value}" />
```

The hard way :

```
<yourComponent attribute="&lt;h:outputText value=&quot;{myExpression}&quot; /&gt;" />
```

Comment: I think you understood me wrong, my attribute is plain text, it is not my goal to parse a component Tag into an String to put it into an attribute, but to output an example of working code with an EL in an attribute.

Comment: @mondjunge No, I understood you correctly, you only not understood the answer.

Comment: that may be. ;) It looks more complicated than what I did. Nazars answer is more what i looked for. thx anyway :)

Comment: Sure it is :) The only complain is will you put long codes inside these examples? If yes, you should consider using a WYSIWYG as input and database as storage maybe?!

Comment: The examples are rather small, A tag and 1 to 5 attributes. The ELs mostly contain image or massage Maps, things like #{message['info']} or #{image['edit_pencil']}. There is no need to store the examples in a database, but I understand your concern, thx for pointing it out.