# Random function not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apache, tomcat, random

I have a JavaScript on a webpage wherein it has a code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
```

But it is not running, i.e., it is not generating a random number. I tried to check it via an alert this way:

```
alert('${Math.random() * 100}');
```

but it is showing "0" as the output.
This Webpage is hosted on Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 server.

While this JavaScript is running fine on Apache Server.

I want to know: how we can make this random function work and is there are some alternatives to it?

Comment: if the javascript is on the page I highly doubt that the server has any bearings to the problem.

Comment: Also, you probably meant to use backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: `it is not generating a random number` then *what* happens? The server has no bearing on the JS that's running. Esecially considering he JS will be running *in the browser* not on the server. `alert('${Math.random() * 100}'); but its showing "0" as output` this cannot be possible. You have a plain string in the alert, you'd get the string shown in a popup, not zero.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You mean it is the browser who isn't able to display it correctly?

Comment: @KaushalShakya exactly

Comment: @KaushalShakya the browser is executing the JS. The server has absolutely no effect on how the code would operate.

Comment: But I have it on my localhost and I am running the webpage on the same browser.

Comment: @KaushalShakya that's irrelevant

Comment: @KaushalShakya again, the server has no effect on the JavaScript executed in the browser.

Comment: Now that I think of it, since you're using tomcat, are you sure you're not serving this as part of a jsf page? Because that would in fact render as `alert(\`0\`)`. If that's the case, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833379/how-to-output-el-as-example#16833687)

Comment: I know it is independent of the server since the browser renders it. But, I have an Apache Server running at localhost/my-web-page/ and here the Js works fine whereas on tomcat server at localhost:8080/my-web-page/ it isn't working. Hence, I thought that there maybe some connection,

Comment: @KaushalShakya as per the answer I linked, just try and put a slash before the expression, as in `alert(\`\${Math.random() * 100}\`);`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it worked!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca can you help me correct this Js to work correctly just as you told me to put a slash: https://codepen.io/nashvail/pen/wpGgXO

Comment: @KaushalShakya that seem to be working already. I mean, I see balls jumping around. Anyway, either the fix is the same or not, and in the latter case you should open a new question **pointing out that you're serving this as a JSF file**. On a related note, you should really strive to put JS in a `.js` file, not on the page.

Comment: @federico Sure, I'll post. Also, can you explain me why it was running fine on Apache Environment on same browser?

Comment: Because Apache doesn't serve JSFs.

Comment: I have corrected every line but can't correct line no 31 i.e., : transform: `translate(${to.x}rem, ${to.y}rem)`

Comment: As When I was placing the slash, this line 31 generated an error.

Comment: ...and yes, the JavaScript is working fine as you have seen the colored jumping balls. What I meant is... what changes should I make so that it'll run fine on Tomcat considering the JSF you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in your local browser, not on the server.

also the correct log would be:

```
alert(`${Math.random() * 100}`);
```

Note the backtick (not apex) enclosing the string.

The backtick is used to implement string templates.

```js
alert(`${Math.random() * 100}`);
```

Comment: Corrected, still getting a "0" on page load.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca snippet IS present, pay attention when reviewing.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I'm not reviewing, I'm saying that the snippet is insufficient in diagnosing the problem, pay attention when commenting. EDIT: I see what happened here. My previous comment was directed at OP, not you. Sorry for the snark.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no problem, mate

Comment: This is the script:  codepen.io/nashvail/pen/wpGgXO

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini the solution you gave isn't working. But it worked when I added a slash (\) after the backtick. Can you suggest any solution to make this Javascript work: https://codepen.io/nashvail/pen/wpGgXO
 especially at line 31, since I tried putting backtick and a slash but the Browser console is showing error at line 31 (maybe syntax error).